# mysql UNION duplicates

Tags: php, mysql, union

I'm using this mysql query and to sort it, I have added bool column *is_main* (is it from main table). The result is working but I'm getting duplicates, because of that *is_main* column.. Is there any fix for this? 
Query:

```
SELECT 
    b.dateTime,
    a.id,
    a.jobName,
    a.is_main
FROM job_data a, data b
WHERE a.userEmail = b.userEmail AND a.userEmail = :email
UNION
SELECT 
    b.dateTime,
    b.id,
    b.jobName,
    b.is_main
FROM job_data a, data b
WHERE a.userEmail = b.userEmail AND a.userEmail = :email

ORDER BY is_main DESC
```

The job_data table:

```
id | dateTime | jobName | is_main
1  | 00.00.00 | job1    | 0
2  | 00.00.00 | job2    | 0
3  | 00.00.00 | job3    | 0
```

The data table:

```
id | dateTime | jobName | is_main
1  | 00.00.00 | job1    | 1
2  | 00.00.00 | ---     | 1
```

The output goes something like this :

```
job1  //this is not okay, because of duplicate job1
job1
job2 
job3 
_____
---  //this is perfect, because I want empty cell to show on top
job1
job2
job3
```

Comment: What is duplicated exactly? I'd recommend to show a sample of output.

Comment: @YakovL I edited the question, to show output and tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT dateTime, id, jobName, max(is_main) from
( SELECT 
    b.dateTime,
    a.id,
    a.jobName,
    a.is_main
FROM job_data a, data b
WHERE a.userEmail = b.userEmail AND a.userEmail = :email
UNION
SELECT 
    b.dateTime,
    b.id,
    b.jobName,
    b.is_main
FROM job_data a, data b
WHERE a.userEmail = b.userEmail AND a.userEmail = :email

)
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: as far as i know, UNION is the same as UNION DISTINCT

Comment: You are correct, I wasn't thinking clearly, obviously. :)

Comment: Can you not exclude the is_main column from your result set, but use it for sorting in your ORDER BY clause? (In your sample data, job1 has an id of 1 for both tables, is that consistent?)

Comment: how can I do that? (yes, ids are the same)

Comment: I've just updated my answer with a new query, let me know if that helps

Comment: nop, seems like this doesn't work.. thanks for the input though :)

Comment: This should have thrown an error because the table doesn't have an alias. Try adding one, adding an alias to `max(is_main)` ie  `max(is_main) as is_from_main_table` then ordering by `is_from_main_table`. After that it looks like it *should* work

Comment: @tomb oh sweet lord! I had to group it also by date and it works!!! Thank you!! now i just have to understand why :D ?